# Why do the leafs of peppermint plant look ill?

Tags: plant-health, mint

In the image below that I just took of my peppermint plant you can see that the leafs have this silver-grayish spots that don't look healthy. What am I doing wrong? Is it too much sun maybe?

[image]

Comment: Welcome blues! By any chance did you mean to say "peppermint" instead of "spearmint" in the title? Unfortunately, I can't help with the diagnosis. I don't know mint plants well (don't worry, we have plenty of people who do) but I just wanted to make sure the title and question both had the same plant name! Can you clarify that and edit it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Mint usually does not mind a lot of sun provided there is water to go with it, otherwise it can dry out quite fast if it is not deeply rooting. As to your leaf issues, I think maybe there are two possibilities: some of the leaves are showing a kind of salt-shake spotting of the leaf, and one or two of the large leaves are possibly showing tunnels. The first damage is typical of leaf hoppers; they jump to the leaf, bite, suck and jump again. So the result is a lot of closely spaced spots where the leaf has been damaged. The big leaf towards the centre of the image shows what looks like a continuous line along one of the subordinate veins; examine this closely and see if it might be a leaf miner. In both cases you should be able to find a culprit in the act of chewing the leaf. Once you can make a positive identification you can move on to what measures to take against the damage. You can find further info and countermeasures on the leafhoppers [here](http://ipm.uconn.edu/documents/view.php?id=440) from the University of Connecticut IPM Program.

Comment: I upvoted this answer, but multiple inspections have not yet discovered any leafhoppers or other visible pests.